# PHP MD5 implementation not working

Tags: php

```
 <?php

$var1;
$var2;

function strToBin($input)
{   
    global $var1;
    global $var2;

    $var1=0;
    $l=strlen($input);
    for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++)
    {
        $arr[$i]=ord($input[$i]);
    }
    for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++)
    {
        $ar2[$i]=sprintf("%08d",decbin($arr[$i]));
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
    print_r($ar2);
    echo "<br><br>";
    $var1=implode($ar2);
    echo "<br><br>";
    $var2=strlen($var1);
    echo strlen($var1);
}

function append()
{
    global $var1;
    global $var2;

    if (strlen($var1)%448==strlen($var1))
    {
        pad(448-strlen($var1));
    }

    else if(strlen($var1)%448!=0)
    {
        pad(strlen($var1)%448);
        echo "hello";

    }   
    else if (strlen($var1)%448==1)
    {
        pad(1);
    }
}

function pad($p)
{
    echo "<br>";
    echo $p;
    global $var1;
    if ($p==1)
    {
        $var1=$var1.(0b1);  
    }
    else 
    {   $var1=$var1.(0b1);

        for ($i=0;$i<$p-1;$i++)
        {
            $var1=$var1.(0b0);
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";    
    echo $var1;
}   

function add_len()
{
    global $var1;
    global $var2;

    $h=sprintf("%08d",decbin($var2));
    echo "<br>";
    echo $h;
    $len_h=strlen($h);

    while(64-$len_h!=0)
    {
        $h=$h.(0b0);
        $len_h++;
    }
    echo "<br><br>";

    $addstr=implode(array_reverse(str_split($h,8)));
    echo strlen($addstr);

    $var1=$var1.$addstr;
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo strlen($var1);
}


function F($X, $Y, $Z)  
{
    $X = hexdec($X);
    $Y = hexdec($Y);
    $Z = hexdec($Z);
    $calc = (($X & $Y) | ((~ $X) & $Z)); // X AND Y OR NOT X AND Z
    return  $calc; 
}

function G($X, $Y, $Z)
{
    $X = hexdec($X);
    $Y = hexdec($Y);
    $Z = hexdec($Z);
    $calc = (($X & $Z) | ($Y & (~ $Z))); // X AND Z OR Y AND NOT Z
    return  $calc;  
}

function H($X, $Y, $Z)
{
    $X = hexdec($X);
    $Y = hexdec($Y);
    $Z = hexdec($Z);
    $calc = ($X ^ $Y ^ $Z); // X XOR Y XOR Z
    return  $calc;  
}

function I($X, $Y, $Z)
{
    $X = hexdec($X);
    $Y = hexdec($Y);
    $Z = hexdec($Z);
    $calc = ($Y ^ ($X | (~ $Z))) ; // Y XOR (X OR NOT Z)
    return  $calc;  
}



function rotateL($a,$b)
{
    return dechex(($a<<$b)|($a>>(32-$b)));
}

function md()
{
    global $var1;
    $g;
    $cal;
    $A0="67452301";
    $B0="EFCDAB89";
    $C0="98BADCFE";
    $D0="10325476";

    $s=array( 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22
        ,5,  9, 14, 20, 5,  9, 14, 20, 5,  9, 14, 20, 5,  9, 14, 20
        ,4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23
        ,6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21);

    print_r($s);

    $k=array( 0xd76aa478, 0xe8c7b756, 0x242070db, 0xc1bdceee
        ,0xf57c0faf, 0x4787c62a, 0xa8304613, 0xfd469501
        ,0x698098d8, 0x8b44f7af, 0xffff5bb1, 0x895cd7be
        ,0x6b901122, 0xfd987193, 0xa679438e, 0x49b40821
        ,0xf61e2562, 0xc040b340, 0x265e5a51, 0xe9b6c7aa
        ,0xd62f105d, 0x02441453, 0xd8a1e681, 0xe7d3fbc8
        ,0x21e1cde6, 0xc33707d6, 0xf4d50d87, 0x455a14ed
        ,0xa9e3e905, 0xfcefa3f8, 0x676f02d9, 0x8d2a4c8a
        ,0xfffa3942, 0x8771f681, 0x6d9d6122, 0xfde5380c
        ,0xa4beea44, 0x4bdecfa9, 0xf6bb4b60, 0xbebfbc70
        ,0x289b7ec6, 0xeaa127fa, 0xd4ef3085, 0x04881d05
        ,0xd9d4d039, 0xe6db99e5, 0x1fa27cf8, 0xc4ac5665
        ,0xf4292244, 0x432aff97, 0xab9423a7, 0xfc93a039
        ,0x655b59c3, 0x8f0ccc92, 0xffeff47d, 0x85845dd1
        ,0x6fa87e4f, 0xfe2ce6e0, 0xa3014314, 0x4e0811a1
        ,0xf7537e82, 0xbd3af235, 0x2ad7d2bb, 0xeb86d391);

    $n=strlen($var1)/512;
    $var3=str_split($var1,512);

    for ($j=0;$j<$n;$j++)
    {   
        $A=$A0;
        $B=$B0;
        $C=$C0;
        $D=$D0;

        $M=str_split($var3[$j],32);

        for($i=0;$i<63;$i++)
        {
            if($i>=0&&$i<=15)
            {
                $cal=F($B,$C,$D);
                $g=$i;  
            }

            if($i>=16&&$i<=31)
            {
                $cal=G($B,$C,$D);
                $g=(5*$i+1)%16; 
            }

            if($i>=32&&$i<=47)
            {
                $cal=H($B,$C,$D);
                $g=(3*$i+5)%16; 
            }

            if($i>=48&&$i<=63)
            {
                $cal=I($B,$C,$D);
                $g=(7*$i)%16;   
            }

            $tempD=$D;
            $D=$C;
            $C=$B;
                 $B=$B+rotateL($A+$cal+hexdec($k[$i])+bindec($M[$g]),$s[$i]);//things
            $A=$tempD;
        }

        $A0=hexdec($A0);
        $B0=hexdec($B0);
        $C0=hexdec($C0);
        $D0=hexdec($D0);
        $A=hexdec($A);
        $B=hexdec($B);
        $C=hexdec($C);
        $D=hexdec($D);

        $A0=$A0+$A;
        $B0=$B0+$B;
        $C0=$C0+$C;
        $D0=$D0+$D;

        $A0=dechex($A0);
        $B0=dechex($B0);
        $C0=dechex($C0);
        $D0=dechex($D0);
        $A=dechex($A);
        $B=dechex($B);
        $C=dechex($C);
        $D=dechex($D);
    }
    $digest=$A0.$B0.$C0.$D0;

    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "The checksum is: ".$digest;       
}

$st="hello world!";
echo $st;


echo "<br>";
strToBin($st);
append();
add_len();

echo "<br><br><br>";
md();

echo"<br><br><br>";
echo $var2;

?>
```

Im getting the wrong checksum. Im sure Ive messed up the md() function. Some help would be appreciated. The correct checksum is ="fc3ff98e8c6a0d3087d515c0473f8677".

im making an MD5 encryption program in PHP. The code runs fine, just the output is incorrect. It looks like a logical error.

Comment: Are you doing it for practicing or practical use?

Comment: MD5 is a hash and PHP has a builtin function for that. http://php.net/md5

Comment: What is the problem to use built-in PHP hash function(s) for that?

Comment: This is purely for the purpose of practicing + a project